# How to test element of custom sdk android unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I've started learning android unit tests, but it looks very hard to find some good guides or information. Every example have a stupid example about 2+2 = 4

Say I write a little SDK which has few functions

```
MySdk.Init(Context context)
MySdk.CallTask()
```

I create an `androidTest` file

How should I call my SDK functions to check how they work? Somewhere required parameters like int/string/context. I just really don't understand, please help me.

This is what I've tried

```
public class AndroidTest {
    private Activity context;


//default test
@Test
public void addition_correct() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
}

@Test
public void checkContext() {
    context = getActivity();
    assertNotNull(context);
}

@Test
public void testInitPhase() {

    MySdk.Init(context, new SdkInitializationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccessful(String adv_id) {
            assert (adv_id != null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationError() {

        }
    });
}
```

}

For context i was tried `context = new mockContext();`. It's passed as `context = null` and my SDK failed with initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests are mainly about testing an individual class in isolation, so that you can check if individual public methods of a class behave as you intend them to, and continue to do so if you change that class' code in the future. Let's say you have a class like this:

```
public class UtilityFunctions {
    public int double(int value) {
        return value * 2;
    }

    public String mirror(String value) {
         if (value == null) return "";
         return value + new StringBuilder(value).reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

You want to test these two methods with:

- valid input values, and check the output is as expected
- invalid values, and check that errors are handled accordingly (and the correct exceptions thrown if necessary)

So a test class for the above class may look like this

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class UtilityFunctionsTest {
    private UtilityFunctions utility;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Initialises any conditions before each test
        utility = new UtilityFunctions();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoubleFunction() {
         assertEquals(2, utility.double(1));
         assertEquals(8, utility.double(4));
         assertEquals(-12, utility.double(-6));
         assertEquals(0, utility.double(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMirror() {
         assertEquals("", utility.mirror(null));
         assertEquals("", utility.mirror(""));
         assertEquals("aa", utility.mirror("a"));
         assertEquals("MirrorrorriM", utility.mirror("Mirror"));
    }
}
```

These standard Java unit tests are run from the `test` directory. However, you'll need to run tests in the `androidTest` directory whenever you're using **Android-specific classes** such as `Context`. If you're creating a `MockContext`, you're simply creating an empty `Context` whose methods don't do anything.

Without me knowing anything about what your `MySDK` does, I think you may need to pass a fully-functioning `Context` into your class for your tests. The Android JUnit runner does provide this with [`InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html#getTargetContext()), so for your example, you may need to add this `@Before` method:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
}
```

You'll also need to remove the `context = getActivity();` line from your first test.

Comment: hey  thank for your answer, i have error : its not found 
InstrumentationRegistry what i should add ?

Comment: Firstly, is your test class in the `androidTest` folder? Secondly, have you got `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` at the top of your class? (Above `public class AndroidTest`)

Comment: See also: [Building instrumented unit tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html)

Comment: sorry i found, i have wrong declaration for this in build.gradle

Comment: No worries, if it's all working for you and this answer's helped, then please upvote and accept (✔)

Comment: i trying to use ur example : i get this error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation. Realy i dont undertand how to run them.

Comment: You haven't defined `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` in your `build.gradle` file. Take some time to [read through the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html) and make sure you follow all the steps.

Comment: Unbelivable , im going by tutorial , official tutorial and i got error on line 
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) why why its happened ? If use JUnit4.class than no error. But instrumentation not working. omg 9((((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161119/discussion-between-michael-dodd-and-peter).